# Data shifting in x-axis while using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am creating the distribution of irradiance in each month for the year 2014 to 2018. The graph for the first three months looks fine as the points lie in each year, then the data points slowly start to move right of the axis and by the time its December, the 2018 data is displayed in 2019 column.

I am a relatively new user in R and don't have much idea on what is going underneath. Here I attach my code and graphs. Month name was created through the simple command of Month <- months(a) from base library. Please help me with this.

```
ggplot(data = Weather_new, aes(x=DateAndTime, y= KP_sensor), na.rm=TRUE) + 
 geom_point(color = "darkblue", alpha=0.2)+
  facet_wrap(.~Monthnames, ncol=4, strip.position = "top")+
  labs(title = "Irradiance distribution over the years")+ xlab('Years')+ 
  ylab(expression("Irradiance"~"["*W / m^2*"]"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: **Image of Irradiance distribution overt the 5 years from 2014 to 2018**]

Comment: So, what is your question? :) I think in the graph, the axis labels of the year are exactly at 1st January of each year. That is why for instance December 18 is pretty close to the 2019 label.

Comment: If you want the points just above the year name, then you probably don't want to use your datetime values on the x-axis, but a factor with values (2014,...2019) instead.

Comment: Points are lying on the months which do not appear as labels on x-axis.

Comment: @otwtm Yes the problem as I realise now is the data being displayed at individual months within each year. that may be the reason why points shift away from the year point in x-axis. What i wanted to do was to have every months data directly on the year name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a year column and replace the datetime field as *x* value in `aes`:

```
Weather_new <- transform(Weather_new, Year = factor(format(DateAndTime, "%Y")))

ggplot(data = Weather_new, aes(x=Year, y= KP_sensor), na.rm=TRUE) + 
  geom_point(color = "darkblue", alpha=0.2) +
  facet_wrap(.~Monthnames, ncol=4, strip.position = "top") +
  labs(title = "Irradiance distribution over the years") +
  xlab('Years') + ylab(expression("Irradiance"~"["*W / m^2*"]")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked for me. I guess the %m in factor needs to be changed to %y for the year. But in doing so, the year 2014 is displayed as 14 and rest others are displayed as two digit numbers. Am I missing something here? the problem is solved but just need to make it 20XX for every points, so that it is standard figure to publish anywhere.

Comment: For four-digit years, use upper-case %Y instead of lower-case %y

Comment: Whoops! Indeed, use the `%Y` for century-formatted 4-digit years. See edit.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. Thankyou so much!